# Implement Filter Design Pattern for generic cases (i.e. filter specific String attributes)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

*I'm implementing a slight variation of this design pattern (filter)* https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/filter_pattern.htm

What I came across, is that I need to filter a String attribute (say, "name") of a list of objects.

The question here is, should I implement a filter/criteria class for every name in existence? *I really don't think so.* There should be a better and more modular way to adapt this:

See, interfaces in java require every method in them to be implemented by the classes. This means, if I want to make a NameCriteria class, I cannot give its method `meetCriteria(List<Person> persons)` two parameters (like a String to filter).

Is there a practical and less hardcoded way to implement this pattern, so I can make a `meetCriteria(List<Person> persons, String name)` method, or any workaround to this?

Comment: I'm currently making an external filtering function to the design pattern, but it feels unnatural. If I don't get a better solution I'll post my workaround here in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That design pattern is obsolete since the addition of the `Stream` API in Java 8. Criteria are now defined by the `Predicate` interface and executed by the `filter` method.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Person john = new Person("John Doe", Gender.MALE, MaritalStatus.MARRIED);
    Person jane = new Person("Jane Doe", Gender.FEMALE, MaritalStatus.MARRIED);
    Person joe  = new Person("Joe Bloe", Gender.MALE, MaritalStatus.SINGLE);

    Set<Person> husbands = Stream.of(john, jane, joe)
            .filter(person -> person.gender == Gender.MALE)
            .filter(person -> person.maritalStatus == MaritalStatus.MARRIED)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

enum Gender {  MALE, FEMALE  }
enum MaritalStatus { MARRIED, SINGLE }
static class Person {
    final String name;
    final Gender gender;
    final MaritalStatus maritalStatus;

    Person(String name, Gender gender, MaritalStatus maritalStatus){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }
}
```